# Uploading a file from front-end to firebase storage via cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I am trying to achieve the following:

1. User selects file on website
2. User calls Firebase Cloud function and passes file into the function
3. Cloud function uploads the file that to storage.

So far I am able to do all of the above, however, when I try to access the above file in storage, a file with no extension is downloaded. The original file was a pdf, but I am still unable able to open it with PDF viewers. It appears I am storing something in storage, although I am not exactly sure what.

Here is an example of how my front-end code works:

```
const getBase64 = file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
  reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
});

var document_send = document.getElementById('myFile')
var send_button = document.getElementById('send_button')

send_button.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  var sendDocument = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('sendDocument')
  try {
    await sendDocument({
      docu: await getBase64(document_send.files[0])
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
})
```

Here is an example of how my cloud function works:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

exports.sendDocument = functions.https
  .onCall((data, context) => {
    return admin.storage().bucket()
      .file("randomLocationName")
      //.file("randomLocationName"+".pdf") - tried this also
      .save(data.docu);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.message);
    return error;
  });
});
```

I do not receive an error message as the function runs without error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uploading file to firebase storage via cloud functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74196431/uploading-file-to-firebase-storage-via-cloud-functions)

Comment: That was my original question. Someone was kind enough to solve that section of it, but the error I am now getting might extends beyond the scope of that question and hence I have asked another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`save()`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/latest/storage/file#_google_cloud_storage_File_save_member_1_) function seems to take either a `string` or `Buffer` as first parameter.

```
> save(data: string | Buffer, options?: SaveOptions)
```

The issue arises when you pass the base64 string directly instead of a Buffer. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
return admin.storage().bucket()
  .file("randomLocationName" + ".pdf") // <-- file extension required
  .save(Buffer.from(data.docu, "base64"));
```

Cloud Functions also have a [10 MB max request size](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas) so you won't be able to upload large images that way. You can use Firebase client SDKs to upload files directly, restrict access using [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security) and use [Cloud Storage Triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events) for Cloud Function in case you want to process the file and update the database. Alternatively, use [signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-generate-upload-signed-url-v4#storage_generate_upload_signed_url_v4-nodejs) for uploading the files if you are using GCS without Firebase.

Comment: Thanks for you contribution. I implemented the above. The document appears to have been saved into the correct location with the correct extension etc. However, if I try to open the document, I receive the following error in my browser: Failed to load PDF document.

Comment: @Charmalade can you please share the complete base64 string that you are using i.e  the `data.docu` maybe in a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com) so I can test once?

Comment: It's too long to paste in comments or edit. I just saved a pdf that said the word "test" on it. Perhaps you could run the same through the function?

Comment: @Charmalade do you have `data:application/pdf;base64,` at the start of your string? If yes, then you just need to pass the base64 part. Try `Buffer.from(data.docu.split(",")[1], "base64")`